# WebDAV query for Exchange

Tags: exchange-server, webdav

I am trying to read a public calendar (in public folders) in my Exchange server.
I am sending the following query to my Exchange server, and the server replies with 400 - Bad Request.

```
<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<g:searchrequest xmlns:g=""DAV:"">
  <g:sql>
      SELECT
          ""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"",
          ""urn:schemas:calendar:location"",
          ""urn:schemas:calendar:dtstart"",
          ""urn:schemas:calendar:dtend""
      FROM
          Scope('SHALLOW TRAVERSAL OF ""https://server/public/SomeFolder/SomeCalendar/""')
  </g:sql>
</g:searchrequest>
```

Now that same query works with this store URL:
https://server/exchange/username/calendar/

So I know that's the URL that is wrong in the query.
If I paste the problematic URL in my web browser, it will come up with the calendar, so the URL does seem fine though.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks
Xavier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks SillyMonkey for your input.

Your URL returned the same error but I have found out the problem was with the endpoint I was connecting to to submit the query.

I was posting the query to this URI:

```
string uri = string.Format("{0}/exchange/{1}", server, credentials.UserName);
```

and now changed it to:

```
string uri = string.Format("{0}/public", server);
```

I am a bit surprised that I have to use different endpoints depending whether I am querying the user's mailbox or the public folders, but it seems to be the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try

https://server/public/SomeFolder/SomeCalendar/?cmd=contents